# What is WSAAsyncSelect() function analogue in Apple GCC?

Tags: c++, sockets, gcc, winsock

Please tell me the most painless way of porting WSAAsyncSelect() function to GCC...

Comment: `WSAAsyncSelect` is specific to the Windows platform for which you can target GCC to under Cygwin or MinGW, you should specify OSX platform rather than the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `select()` and `pselect()` may work for your application, they are very much not the same thing as `WSAAsyncSelect()`. Those functions let you do controlled blocking on an otherwise non-blocking socket, or collection of sockets. The same goes for `poll()`.

Winsock's asynchronous sockets, on the other hand, do not block, ever. There's also the large matter of async notifications, which your code doubtless depends on.

I do not believe there are any native APIs on OS X that provide similar behavior. However, it's possible to build up such a thing. A little Googling turned up [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/).

If you would rather not depend on third-party libraries, I suggest building up something on top of Cocoa's [CFSocket](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html), as the CocoaAsyncSocket developers did, if you will be porting over a GUI program, rather than dig down to core functions like `select()`. There's something to be said for using a single development framework for everything.

If you need your code to be cross-platform, the [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) library has the [wxSockets*](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_socket_base.html) class hierarchy, which emulates the Winsock async socket mechanism. Overall, wxWidgets is structured much like MFC, which eases porting if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to look at the [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171270/select-function-in-socket-programming) function

Comment: Thanks for the help, Vink and Jay! If it is not too much to ask, can you please provide some kind of example? I tried to compare arguments of pselect() and WSAAsyncSelect() and took a look at some examples and now I'm totally lost...

Answer (score 1):

I use [pselec](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect)t function.