# How do I time out on a specific socket and specific port without select()?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, sockets, winsock

Looking at the [select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171270/select-function-in-socket-programming) function it seems that it is used to examine multiple event sources.

I have a single socket bound to one port on my server.

Basically want to time out the [recvfrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function after 500ms.

Is select() the best/only way to do this or is it over kill?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select is the best way to set the timeout on the socket file descriptor.  It is not overkill it's actually the proper call that will put your program to sleep until the data is available or timeout occurs which means your program won't lock the system.

Comment: Why is it better than SO_RCVTIMEO?

Comment: No better actually... SO_RCVTIMEO may be better in this case, I just wanted to point out that select is not an overkill in terms of overhead and puts the process to sleep. In either case you would have to check for EAGAIN ...

Answer (score 1):

If you use the socket in blocking mode, then using `select()` to wait for data to arrive before then calling `recvfrom()` is one (and the more common) approach, but another approach is to use `setsockopt()` to set the socket's `SO_RCVTIMEO` option, which sets a timeout for blocking read operations (see `SO_SENDTIMEO` for blocking sending operations).  You can then call `recvfrom()` and let it time out internally.

If you use the socket in non-blocking mode, then you can receive asynchronous `FD_READ` notifications using `WSAASyncSelect()` or `WSAASyncEvent()`.  No need to wait for timeouts.

If you use the socket in overlapped mode, then you can receive asynchronous read notifications from `WSARecvFrom()` using `WSAGetOverlappedResult()` or `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`.  No need to wait for timeouts.