# Why we use threads and select together

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select, pthreads

I'm setting up a server with some clients using socket programming in c.

I found that in order to have more than one client, I should use threads or select or poll.

I know how should I use these function but when I searched I found that there is a way that used from thread and select together.

I have two questions:

1) what is the reason and benefits(**using select and thread together**)?

2) Is thread used for clients and select for reading the socket?

Comment: There are several answers already posted on this site, as well as others, describing client/server architectures.  This _[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173323/645128)_ discusses both threads and select as components of different server approaches.

Comment: @ryyker Yes, I saw most of the posts, but they are all explain why we use select. I want to know why we use select and thread toghether.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle more than one socket/client in one thread by using `select`/`epoll` and non-blocking I/O. You can handle even more sockets/clients if you have multiple threads doing that.

Old but still relevant read [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).